# PowerShell ISE Git GPG Signed Commit Error

Tags: git, commit, gnupg, signed, powershell-ise

If in command line git I sign commit in PowerShell ISE (as admin or not) I get the following error:

> C:\Users\MyName\myrepo> git commit -S -m "Testing signed commit in PowerShell ISE."
>
> `git : gpg: WARNING: unsafe permissions on homedir
>   'C:\Users\Jerry\AppData\Roaming\gnupg' At line:1 char:1
>   + git commit -S -m "Testing signed commit in PowerShell ISE."
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (gpg: WARNING: u...\Roaming\gnupg':String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
>   gpg : cannot open tty no tty': No such file or directory error: gpg failed to sign the
>   data fatal: failed to write commit object`

Signed commits work in command prompt and Powershell console (as admin or not), so I'm guessing GPG is having an issue with ISE?  The error does say permissions are unsafe on "homedir" (where gnupg lives), but I don't know how to make Windows permissions for this directory safe to GPG's requirements (if that's even the problem).

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

GnuPG does not like anybody but your own user account to be able to read and write the contents of the GnuPG home directory (`C:\Users\Jerry\AppData\Roaming\gnupg` in your case), especially not for the private key files contained.

Remove privileges for any other user account but your own, which is possible by [opening the properties and removing permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx).

An alternative would be to set up git to use the `--no-permission-warning` flag, but this is just a workaround and does not really fix the issue.